# Несколько конструкторов с разным количеством аргументов

Tags: python, ооп

Можно ли в Python в одном классе делать несколько конструкторов с разным количеством аргументов?

```
class a:
def __init__(self,b):
    pass
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

В данном случае можно создавать экземпляры класса только со вторым констуктором, в то время как запись x = a(42) вызовет ошибку.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если быть кратким то НЕТ.

Более детально посмотрите обсуждение вот [ЗДЕСЬ](http://younglinux.info/oopython/init.php). Там и варианты решений есть такие как использование необязательных или ключевых аргументов.

Answer (score 7):

В Python'е перегрузок функций (а конструктор, по факту - это функция) нет в принципе. В вашем случае, вызывается всегда второй конструктор, ибо инструкция `def` означает "создать объект функции и присвоить этот объект написанному имени", то есть, сначала вы присваиваете имени `__init__` одну функцию (с параметром `b`), а затем - тому же имени - другую функцию, уже без параметра `b`.

Поведение, которого вы добиваетесь, можно получить, используя параметры по умолчанию, например:

```
def __init__(self, b=None):
    # Здесь лучше придумать что-то отличное от проверки на None
    # больше соответствующее вашей задаче. Возможно, вам просто подойдет
    # какое-то значение по умолчанию.
    if b is None:
        pass
    else:
        pass

# ...

a = a() # b будет равно None по умолчанию
b = a(42) # b будет равно 42
```

Answer (score 1):

еще вариант

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   p = kwargs.get('name','trololo')
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

а не проще сделать так:

```
class Troll():
    def __init__(self, name='trololo', size=42)


# ......

a = Troll()                        # а тут тролль по умолчанию - trololol, 42 
b = Troll('ololol', 12)            # тут у нас получиться маленький тролль с ником ололо
```